# map contact field shows empty in Sitecore custom submit action 10.2

Tags: xdb, sitecore-forms

I have created a custom submit action in the form for Identifying contact based on the form submission. So I have created based on the link https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html

but In the mapping section in the dropdown list coming as empty. Here is the image attached.

*Last Name and FirstName* is null in the dropdown.

[image]

Created 3 fields in the Settings form

1. Email Fied
2. First Name Field
3. Last Name Field

Core Database Settings form screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you show your items from `core` database for mapping those 2 fields? Under `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/Actions/UpdateContact/PageSettings`?

Comment: @MarekMusielak updated the information in the question

Comment: @MarekMusielak any updates?

Comment: I remember that I had similar issue which was caused by wrong casing of letters. One capital letter instead of lowercase or the other way. But don't remember now exactly

Comment: I have changed to uppercase from lowercase. but still is not working